# How to show value in if statement in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5.1

I am doing my project but got stuck in this. I want to print both value of degrees and experiences. How can i achieve this? My controller file is like below:

```
public function industryPost (Request $request) {
        $industry = $request->input('industry');

        if (empty($industry)) {
            return 'Industry can not be null';
        } else {

            $experiences = AreaOfExperience::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();
            $degrees = Degree::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();


            if (!empty($degrees) ) {
                $string2 = '';
                foreach ($degrees as $degree) {
                    $string2 .= '
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="be-checkbox">
                                <label class="check-box">
                                    <input id="degree" type="checkbox" name="degrees[]" value="'.$degree->id.'" class="checkbox-input">
                                    <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
                                </label>
                                <span class="large-popup-text"> '.$degree->name.' </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
                return response($string2);
            }
            if (count($degrees) == 0) {
                return 101;
            }

            if (!empty($experiences) ) {
                $string = '';
                foreach ($experiences as $experience) {
                    $string .= '
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="be-checkbox">
                                <label class="check-box">
                                    <input id="experience" type="checkbox" name="area_of_experiences[]" value="'.$experience->id.'" class="checkbox-input">
                                    <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
                                </label>
                                <span class="large-popup-text"> '.$experience->name.' </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
                return response($string);
            }
            if (count($experiences) == 0) {
                return 100;
            }


        }
    }
```

I want to print both the value of degree and experience. But in my query it prints the value of degree. how can i achieve this? Please help!

Comment: @Komal how can I achieve this? Will you please help? Please give me exemple

Comment: Pass both array to view and generate you UI there

Comment: Did you try below code

Comment: Yes I tried. i dont want to view like this. I want to pass this as an array. Will you please help me fixing this. @Komal

Comment: with this `return response($string2);` the rest of the code will not be executed.so you're getting only the value of degree.

Comment: solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer should be like this

```
public function industryPost (Request $request) {
        $industry = $request->input('industry');

        if (empty($industry)) {
            return 'Industry can not be null';
        } else {

            $experiences = AreaOfExperience::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();
            $degrees = Degree::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();

            $string2 = '';
            if (!empty($degrees) ) {

                foreach ($degrees as $degree) {
                    $string2 .= '
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="be-checkbox">
                                <label class="check-box">
                                    <input id="degree" type="checkbox" name="degrees[]" value="'.$degree->id.'" class="checkbox-input">
                                    <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
                                </label>
                                <span class="large-popup-text"> '.$degree->name.' </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }

            }
            if (count($degrees) == 0) {
                return 101;
            }
            $string = '';

            if (!empty($experiences) ) {

                foreach ($experiences as $experience) {
                    $string .= '
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="be-checkbox">
                                <label class="check-box">
                                    <input id="experience" type="checkbox" name="area_of_experiences[]" value="'.$experience->id.'" class="checkbox-input">
                                    <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
                                </label>
                                <span class="large-popup-text"> '.$experience->name.' </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
            }
            $data = array(
                'string2'=>$string2,
                'string' =>$string
            );

            return response($data);

            if (count($experiences) == 0) {
                return 100;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$experiences = AreaOfExperience::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();
$degrees = Degree::where('industry_id', $industry)->where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();

return view('view_name')->with('experiences', $experiences)->with('degrees', $degrees);
```

Your view

```
@foreach($degrees as $degree)
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="be-checkbox">
          <label class="check-box">
              <input id="degree" type="checkbox" name="degrees[]" value="{{$degree->id}}" class="checkbox-input">
              <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
          </label>
          <span class="large-popup-text">{{$degree->name}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```